# Exclude Friday & Saturday while using DATEDIFF function in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

below is my `SQL` Query used to calculate the number of days between two days

```
SELECT      count(*) as NoofCalls, outside.ReferenceNo, outside.WorkflowType, outside.Department, inside.CompletedDate, outside.CommentResponse, outside.CommentText, outside.CommentUserDisplayName, outside.StepName, outside.Originator, outside.Subject, outside.StartTime, CAST(DATEDIFF(hh, outside.StartTime, inside.CompletedDate) / 24.0 AS decimal(10,5)) AS CompDays
FROM
(
    SELECT      ReferenceNo, MAX(CommentDate) as CompletedDate
    FROM        FNCUSTOM.dbo.WorkflowHistory
    WHERE       WorkflowType IN (@WorkflowType) AND Department IN (@Department) AND Originator IN (@Originator) AND ReferenceNo IN (@Reference_No)
                AND (StartTime between @StartDate AND @EndDate)
    GROUP BY    ReferenceNo
) inside
INNER JOIN  FNCUSTOM.dbo.WorkflowHistory outside ON outside.ReferenceNo = inside.ReferenceNo AND outside.CommentDate=inside.CompletedDAte
GROUP BY    outside.ReferenceNo, outside.WorkflowType, outside.Department, inside.CompletedDate, outside.CommentResponse, outside.CommentText, outside.CommentUserDisplayName, outside.StepName, outside.Originator, outside.Subject, outside.StartTime
```

I require to ***exclude FRIDAY & SATURDAY while calulating CompDays***.

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Using SSRS 2005.
The startdate may start on Thursday (say 2013-04-25 08:58:47.000 ) and endDate (say 2013-04-28 20:58:47.000) then the COMPDAYS should be 1.5 days. Excluding **COMPLETE FRIDAY & SATURDAY**

Comment: How large a number of days might you expect between two dates - will this always be relatively small (say, less than a week), or might it be weeks/months/years?

Comment: @WillA It can be less than a week; and can be more than a week .... very few may go in months .. but not years

Comment: Hi, Can any one help me no this plz

Comment: Hi, Can any one help me on this plz

Comment: Any one , Any ideas :) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed myself,

```
SELECT      count(*) as NoofCalls, outside.ReferenceNo, outside.WorkflowType, outside.Department, inside.CompletedDate, outside.CommentResponse, outside.CommentText, 
    outside.CommentUserDisplayName, outside.StepName, outside.Originator, outside.Subject, outside.StartTime,
                            CAST(DATEDIFF(hh, outside.StartTime, inside.CompletedDate) / 24.0 AS decimal(10,5)) 
                             -(DATEDIFF(wk, outside.StartTime, inside.CompletedDate) * 2)
                             -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, outside.StartTime) = 'Friday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                             -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, inside.CompletedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS CompDays
    FROM
(
            SELECT      ReferenceNo, MAX(CommentDate) as CompletedDate
            FROM        FNCUSTOM.dbo.WorkflowHistory
            WHERE       WorkflowType IN (@WorkflowType) AND Department IN (@Department) AND Originator IN (@Originator) AND ReferenceNo IN (@Reference_No)
                    AND (StartTime between @StartDate AND @EndDate)
            GROUP BY    ReferenceNo
) inside
INNER JOIN  FNCUSTOM.dbo.WorkflowHistory outside ON outside.ReferenceNo = inside.ReferenceNo AND outside.CommentDate=inside.CompletedDAte
GROUP BY               outside.ReferenceNo, outside.WorkflowType, outside.Department, inside.CompletedDate, outside.CommentResponse, outside.CommentText, 
    outside.CommentUserDisplayName, outside.StepName, outside.Originator, outside.Subject, outside.StartTime
ORDER BY               outside.ReferenceNo, outside.WorkflowType, outside.Department, outside.StartTime, inside.CompletedDate, outside.CommentResponse, outside.CommentText, 
    outside.CommentUserDisplayName, outside.StepName, outside.Originator, outside.Subject
```